# Python-gym. Does not see the environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

Please tell me what might be the problem?
Only one environment starts correctly. (Trolley)

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample())
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
>         1 import gym
>   ----> 2 env = gym.make('CarRacing-v0')
>         3 env.reset()
>         4 for _ in range(1000):
>         5     env.render()
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym-0.15.6-py3.6.egg\gym\envs\registration.py
>   in make(id, **kwargs)
>       140 
>       141 def make(id, **kwargs):
>   --> 142     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
>       143 
>       144 def spec(id):
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym-0.15.6-py3.6.egg\gym\envs\registration.py
>   in make(self, path, **kwargs)
>        85             logger.info('Making new env: %s', path)
>        86         spec = self.spec(path)
>   ---> 87         env = spec.make(**kwargs)
>        88         # We used to have people override _reset/_step rather than
>        89         # reset/step. Set _gym_disable_underscore_compat = True on
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym-0.15.6-py3.6.egg\gym\envs\registration.py
>   in make(self, **kwargs)
>        56             env = self.entry_point(**_kwargs)
>        57         else:
>   ---> 58             cls = load(self.entry_point)
>        59             env = cls(**_kwargs)
>        60
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym-0.15.6-py3.6.egg\gym\envs\registration.py
>   in load(name)
>        16     mod_name, attr_name = name.split(":")
>        17     mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
>   ---> 18     fn = getattr(mod, attr_name)
>        19     return fn
>        20
>
> AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'CarRacing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using anaconda but virtualenv. Nevertheless, I had initially the same error. It seems that the "Classical" Environments were working but not the Box2D games. I tried to install Box2D separately with "pip install Box2D" but I received errors for a missing swig.exe when installing dependency "wheel".

To solve this,

- I downloaded [swig](http://www.swig.org/download.html) and then added the path to the swig.exe to my windows path.
- Then I uninstalled gym and Box2D.
- Then I installed gym and then Box2D with "pip install gym[box2d]"

[image]

Comment: That's the way to do it. You need to install various dependencies separately for additional environments - such as swig and mujoco